# Adding attributes to Angular formly "formly-field" div

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-formly

The generated angular formly fields are all wrapped in one of these Divs:
`<div formly-field ng-repeat="field in fields ">...</div>`

I would like to know how do I add extra attributes to this div? I'm using flexbox for responsiveness and would like the Div to be rendered as:
`<div formly-field ng-repeat="field in fields" flex-gt-sm="50" flex-sm="100" flex-xs="100">...</div>`

Answer (score 0):

You probably would need to overwrite formlyForm template using something like that

`

```
.config(['$provide', Decorate]);
   function Decorate($provide) {

       $provide.decorator('formlyFormDirective', function($delegate) {

           var directive = $delegate[0];
           var templateFn = directive.template;
           directive.template = function (el, attrs) {
           var out = templateFn (el, attrs);
           // out is a string so just insert your new attributes wherever you need them
           return out;
       }

       return $delegate;
   });   
}
```

`

Comment: That won't work, as I need to pass in the parameters of what attributes I want to add to the form field div

Comment: Your attributes are available in the argument of the templateFn as attrs. not different from a directive. If you need to do more processing with your attrs then create a directive and insert it in the string. After it is returned, angular will compile it, and see your directive and execute it.

Comment: Should that code work? I get the error Error: $injector:modulerr

Comment: I think the problem is that the decorator should be on formlyFormDirective not formlyForm. Try that

Comment: Still doesn't work. I've got around it by using custom CSS.